# Как получить данные из базы данных Postgresql с помощью C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

У меня есть контекст и какой-то метод, в котором нужно получить данные из таблицы учителей с помощью `using (var db = new ApplicationContext())`. Но как это сделать, если конструктор `ApplicationContext` требует `options`? Что если у меня их нет?

```
class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tutor> Tutors { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
    }
}
```

```
class TutorsRepository : ICrudRepository<Tutor>
{
    public void Get()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну добавьте пустой конструктор в контекст

Comment: Можно просто убрать конструктор с параметром. При этом в методе `OnConfiguring` нужно добавить строку соединения.

Comment: Или создавайте `DbContextOptions` с помощью `DbContextOptionsBuilder` и передавайте в конструктор контекста.

Comment: [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Comment: Почему заголовок вопроса не соответствует его содержимому?